# jQuery autocomplete ui - Really strange 1 letter delay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I'm having some problems with [jQuery Autocomplete UI](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). I have one input and I get the value of this input to make a JSON search, suggesting things from database.

The stange is, if I type `test` in input, the printed value just before the autocomplete is `test`, but when I print it inside the autocomplete, the value is `tes`. In other words, I'm having a 1 letter delay when open and search with Autocomplete.

### My code (edited):

```
input.on('keyup propertychange paste', function(event){
    console.log("Inserted: " + myTextFromInput);

    input.autocomplete({
        delay: 0,
        minLength: 0,
        disabled: false,
        source: function(request, response) {

            // I need this value in my code
            originalValue = input.val();

            // Printing the current value of this variable
            console.log("Searched: " + myTextFromInput);

            if (myTextFromInput != null){

                // Remove all "?" from this string
                term = myTextFromInput.replace('?','')

                // Call the method to search in database
                populate(term, response)

                // Filtering
                result = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(result, request.term)

                // Prevent a lot of "loading" items
                for (var i in result){
                  if (result[i].type === "loading"){
                    var deleteItem = result.indexOf(i)
                    result.splice(deleteItem, 1);
                  }
                } 

                // Add item "loading" to array
                var item = {};
               item.type = 'loading';
               item.label = "Loading..";
               item.value = "";

               result.push(item);
            }
        } 
    })

    var populate = function(term, response) {
        $.getJSON(
          'text.json', // Rails, you don't need to understand
          {search: term},
          function(json) {
            var result = [];
            $.each(json, function(key, value) {
              var item = {};
              item.type = ' ';
              item.label = value.name;
              item.value = value.name;
              result.push(item);
            }) //END EACH

            var item = {};
            item.type = "noneResult";
            item.label = "Sent us your suggestion ('" + term + "')."; 
            item.value = term;
            result.push(item)

            response(result);
          }
        ); //END FUNCTION 
    };
});
```

And here's what I get from console, for e.g:

```
>> Inserted: myAwesomeTest
>> Searched: myAwesomeTes
```

#### What can I do to remove this letter delay?

Answer (score 1):

How do you fill your `myTextFromInput` variable ?

Could you show more context around the code you posted ? Is it inside a function ?
Is it called once inside `$(document).ready(...)`, or on each keystroke ?

---

The term you should look for is the `request` argument.

```
input.autocomplete({
       ...
       source: function(request, repsonse) {
           // Remove all "?" from this string
           var term = request.term;
           term = term.replace('?','');

           ...
       }
 );
```

Comment: Sure, I will update the question soon. About your code, when I try to `console.log(request)` it gives me `[object Object]`, so I think if I use request.replace it will give an error, or am I wrong?

Comment: @FernandoPaladini: corrected ([doc here](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source))

Comment: I'm receiving some errors when I try to edit my question, soon as I can I will update the question.

Comment: Just to be clear : `$.autocomplete()` is not meant to be called each time you want to query for an autocompletion. It is meant to be called once, and sets up the widget which will allow to query for an autocompletion each time you press a key.  
The function which will be called on each keystroke is `source: function(...){ ... }`

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log("Inserted: " + myTextFromInput);

input.autocomplete({
delay: 0,
minLength: 0,
disabled: false,
source: function(request, response) {

      // I need this value in my code
      originalValue = input.val();

      // Printing the current value of this variable
      console.log("Searched: " + myTextFromInput);

      if (myTextFromInput != null){

        // Remove all "?" from this string
        term = myTextFromInput.replace('?','')

        // Call the method to search in database
        populate(term, response)

        // Filtering
        result = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(result, request.term)

        // Prevent a lot of "loading" items
        for (var i in result){
          if (result[i].type === "loading"){
            var deleteItem = result.indexOf(i)
            result.splice(deleteItem, 1);
          }
        } 

        // Add item "loading" to array
        var item = {};
        item.type = 'loading';
        item.label = "Loading..";
        item.value = "";

        result.push(item);
      }
} 
})

var xhr;

var populate = function(term, response) {
    if(xhr && xhr.readyState != 4){
        xhr.abort();
    }


    xhr = $.getJSON(
      '<%= my_path %>.json', // Rails, you don't need to understand
      {search: term},
      function(json) {
        var result = [];
        $.each(json, function(key, value) {
          var item = {};
          item.type = ' ';
          item.label = value.name;
          item.value = value.name;
          result.push(item);
        }) //END EACH

        var item = {};
        item.type = "noneResult";
        item.label = "Sent us your suggestion ('" + term + "')."; 
        item.value = term;
        result.push(item)

        response(result);
      }
    ); //END FUNCTION 
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but what is "xhr", what your method do? Doesn't fixed my problem, but I think we're going to. Can you explain better and maybe help me fix that?

Comment: xhr is just a js variable. What I'm trying to do here is that I'm aborting the handling of previous ajax request's response whenever a new request(new character is typed in the box) is created.

Comment: Thanks! This appears to not work, have you more tips or suggestions?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle? instead of '<%= my_path %>.json' give a proper url which will return a result.

Comment: I have more than 320 lines of JS, I will must explain all project that my team is working on, and I can't do that :/ Let's do the following: you tell me what you want to know and I tell you, okay?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when coding my own typeahead search - when I used keydown, I got a one letter delay, but when using keyup it worked as it was supposed to.

Comment: Thanks, I do that and fixed some bugs in my code, but the bug of this question wasn't solved with your code. Anyway, thanks! :)

Comment: Ran into the same thing and went with 'keypress' as it (the event) provided my character 'e.which' and was restricted to only character keys.